# On assigning moral trues?

Tags: ethics

Let's say a person has a moral system and he believes can assign moral truths to moral philosophies.

Now, let's assume I have an individual who does not subscribe in ideas of truth. Rather he believes in ideas of relevance (see John Vervake on this topic). His moral system is: "he will conduct himself in a way which is relevant to his life."

So if the person with the moral code asks the other individual about being wronged (according to his world view) then the other individual would respond: "I will react to the situation in a way relevant to what I know, to what I feel and what I see, who I am, who I've been ,etc etc"

Are there a moral systems that are valid (taken seriously in academia) and that the moral individual can hold which will enable him in assigning moral truths assign a moral truth of good or evil, right or wrong, etc etc to the moral code of the relevance subscriber?

Comment: idt this is necessarily opinion based (rather than offering less room for opining than others may want)

Comment: Hey (to the closer) I've edited the question.... There should be possible answer this. Also going back and forth between world views to frame a question is hard.( So apologies for the number of edits)

Comment: Why does the moral system of another person preclude you from applying your moral code to their actions. That seems to be done all the time.

Comment: @Annika I suspect the problem would be working out the time evolution of the system. Now to assign or guess the moral philosophy I need to know a whole lotta stuff (initial conditions)

Comment: I would argue this would enable me to differentiate between people who follow false ideology and people who are inherently evil (common ground language)

Comment: Notice because of evolution the latter would be unlikely

Comment: *Now to assign or guess the moral philosophy's moral truth

Comment: What does time evolution have to do with it? If I say that murdering babies is never justified and you say that murdering babies is justified if it is relevant to the way you feel (maybe because you hate the baby for being a member of a society that oppresses you), then there is no time evolution involved in me observing that you are objectively evil. No response by you to my judgment will have any effect on my judgment.

Comment: @DavidGudeman okay so I just disagree with this way of doing moral philosophy. Where we can have thought experiment of what I did ...  claim an unlikely claim and then claim it is relevant to rest of culture

Comment: In that context, what the heck is murdering babies is justified if it is relevant to the way you feel (maybe because you hate the baby for being a member of a society that oppresses you),

Comment: This sounds more like incoherence and probably mental illness to me or maybe the affects of medication or low IQ disability .... We already have standards for that in society

Comment: It's called an example. They are a common device in philosophy.

Comment: @DavidGudeman fair point